# In XSD's request for the permission of type 'system.security.permissions.fileiopermission mscorlib version=4.0.0.0

Tags: validation, xsd

I am validating my request using xxx.XSD file. In xxx.XSD file I am including another xsd files also.
When I am trying to inlcude another xsd file using , it is showing below error.

"Request for the permission of type 'system.security.permissions.fileiopermission mscorlib version=4.0.0.0  cultrer='neutral, PublicToken='zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' failed.

Note: I am not using any web.conig file. It is simple ClassLibraryProject in VSStudio2010,
In vb class file I am doing xsd validation for request xml before sending it to service for response.

Answer (score 24):

Had this issue myself - it was because Win 7 had blocked the schema files due to them being copied in from a network location.

To unblock, either navigate to the file and use Properties > Unblock, or for multiple files it's quickest to use Sysinternals' Streams to bulk change the location as described [in this blog post](http://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2010/09/01/how-to-bulk-unblock-files-in-windows-7-or-server-2008/).